# Locating the Errored emails on a Triggered Email Send

Tags: email, triggered-send, marketing-cloud

I have a triggered email send that is getting quite a few errors. I've got send logging enabled, so these error codes should be getting pulled into that data extension. However, I'm unsure what the column heading is supposed to be. Is it 'Errorcode'? Unsure what to label this so I can properly view the error codes and information on the send log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErrorCode is the correct heading where this information will populate. The field is added by default when creating a DE from the sendlog template.